# Set of order preserving functions

Tags: function-construction, memory, sets

I have a partial order defined on a finite set, 13 elements, represented as a directed graph. I'm trying to work with the set of order preserving functions from this poset into a finite subset of the natural numbers containing 0, Y. I worked out how to construct the set of all functions (as associations), but that's |Y|^13, which is way too big. That's already on the order of gigabytes of memory with just Y={0,1,2,3,4}. Only a small fraction of those are order preserving though. I have no idea where to start with constructing just the order preserving ones. Any ideas or help is appreciated.

This is the poset:

```
L = {a \[DirectedEdge] b, a \[DirectedEdge] c, b \[DirectedEdge] e, 
b \[DirectedEdge] d, b \[DirectedEdge] i, c \[DirectedEdge] d, 
c \[DirectedEdge] g, c \[DirectedEdge] h, d \[DirectedEdge] f, 
d \[DirectedEdge] h, d \[DirectedEdge] i, e \[DirectedEdge] h, 
f \[DirectedEdge] j, f \[DirectedEdge] l, g \[DirectedEdge] i, 
h \[DirectedEdge] j, h \[DirectedEdge] k, i \[DirectedEdge] k, 
i \[DirectedEdge] l, j \[DirectedEdge] m, k \[DirectedEdge] m, 
l \[DirectedEdge] m}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce). First convert the poset relations into a set of inequalities:

```
ineq = Less @@@ L;
```

Next, extract the points of the poset:

```
v = Union @ Flatten @ Apply[List, L, {1}]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m}

Using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce):

```
Reduce[
    And @@ ineq && And @@ Thread[0 <= v <= 4],
    Integers
]
```

> False

Apparently, it is not possible to create an order preserving function with only 5 integers. Increasing the range by 1 does yield a solution:

```
Reduce[
    And @@ ineq && And @@ Thread[0 <= v <= 5],
    Integers
]
```

> a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 2 && e == 2 && f == 3 && g == 2 && h == 3 &&
>     i == 3 && j == 4 && k == 4 && l == 4 && m == 5